# Video card recommendation

Tags: graphics, video, hardware

I have a Club-3D CGNX-G952YLI GeForce 9500GT video card in my PC with VGA and DVI output, and for a while it is started overheating. Therefore I would like to buy another one, however I couldn't find the same card on the market. Therefore I would like to buy a video card which works under Ubuntu, and has the same bus and interfaces (1xVGA, 1xDVI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Nvidia cards have drivers for Ubuntu. And there are lots of Nvidia cards with DVI and VGA outputs. You can buy any of those.

Answer (score 3):

Generally the open source video driver works well for most applications that are not using the video card a lot, but there is also the proprietary NVidia driver you can install through `Software and Updates -> Additional Drivers` and unless the card you choose is very recent (in which case it could be unstable without updates) there should be no problem at all.